# execute bundle who cintains xml parser (SAX)

Tags: xml, osgi, bundle, sax, ipojo

i want to run bundle who contains code of parser xml(SAX)   when i execute the commande  start file:bundle's path i have a problem

> this is the error msg

```
 -> start file:C:\felix\bundles\home.analyser-1.0.0.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle home.analyse
r [13]: package; (package=org.xml.sax.helpers)
```

> i  try to search the jar file on the net but i don't found it

could someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*org.xml.sax.helpers* package is part of the JDK. Your issue can be that this package is not included in the system packages of the OSGi container.

In case you want to use it from a bundle instead of the JDK, you can install the [org.everit.osgi.bundles.org.apache.xmlcommons.full](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22org.everit.osgi.bundles.org.apache.xmlcommons.full%22) bundle exports all packages of the [Apache XMLCommons](https://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/) project and contains the apache implementation.